# Word wrapping text without splitting words

Tags: parsing, text, vb6, word-wrap

I'm looking for a procedure in VB6 to parse strings (with variable lengths) without splitting any word.
I have many strings and I have to write each of them (looping) to an image.

An example string is: "*Il punto di vista si trova in corrispondenza del Forte Matiniti inferiore. Le opere e le aree di intervento previste dal Progetto Definitivo (Ottobre 2010) e inquadrabili dalla stazione visiva sono: il Centro Direzionale e il cantiere operativo CI3b; le due torri di sostegno e i cavi tra Torre e blocco di cemento. Sullo sfondo è visibile la costa siciliana.*"

How do I write it, for example, in a 3 lines, without splitting words?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to word wrap the text? The VB6 Textbox does this by default when `MultiLine` is set to true and `ScrollBars` is not set to both or horizontal.

Comment: Thanks Deanna. The textbox in which I've to write the string it is not a VB6 textbox. I've to write it in a delimited space on a JPEG layout (I know the x,y coords where to put the text in the layout).

Comment: Ok, I've updated the question to suit.

Comment: Ia there a max number of character limit per line?

Answer (score 3):

To do word wrapping of text, you need to split it into words on each space, then calculate how much space it will take from the beginning to each space in turn. When it goes above the area to fit in, you print out everything up to the pervious space then start again on the new line.

As the text size is determined by the font in use, you will need to query the drawing library to see how big each chunk will be. If using GDI, you can use the `GetTextExtentPoint32()` function. If drawing to a VB6 picturebox before creating the JPEG, you can use the `.TextWidth()` method.

Also note that the GDI `DrawText()` function has an option to break on words automatically given a Rect.

You'll need to provide more information on how you're doing the drawing and creating the image for a more specific answer.

Comment: Thanks Deanna, for now unfortunately I've no more time to test your solution. I'll try the next days.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function that should work

```
Private Function FormatString(ByVal StringToFormat As String, ByVal MaxLineLen As Integer) As String
    Dim TempString As String
    Dim Pos As Long

    FormatString = ""
    Pos = 1
    While StringToFormat <> ""
        If Len(StringToFormat) <= MaxLineLen Then
            TempString = Trim(StringToFormat)
        Else
            TempString = Mid(StringToFormat, Pos, MaxLineLen + 1)
            TempString = Trim(Left(TempString, InStrRev(TempString, " ")))
        End If

        FormatString = FormatString & TempString & vbCrLf
        StringToFormat = LTrim(Right(StringToFormat, Len(StringToFormat) - Len(TempString)))
    Wend
End Function
```